# Opening a numbered file in c

Tags: c, file, char, fopen

The issue I am having is simply opening a file which has a number based on an input. 
Example included:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int argument = atoi(argv[1]);
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("/folder/item'argument'file", "r");
  //do stuff to the file
}
```

Example passing 4 will open the file called "item4file" for use

How would I address this?

Sincere thanks for any and all help

Comment: What is the problem with you example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int argument = atoi(argv[1]);  
FILE *fp;
char address[50]; // choose the size that suits your needs
sprintf (address, "/folder/item%dfile", argument);
fp = fopen(address, "r");
```

As you can read [from the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), a terminating null character is automatically appended to the string.

If you want to **avoid buffer overflows**, however, you should use `snprintf` (which is shown in the same reference page as above), declaring the maximum size of the buffer so that the input doesn't overflow it.

```
int argument = atoi(argv[1]);  
FILE *fp;
char address[50]; // choose the size that suits your needs
snprintf (address, 49, "/folder/item%dfile", argument); // 49 since we need one index for our null terminating character
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! This is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

use `sprintf()` as

```
char filename[50]
strcpy(filename,"/folder/item");
sprintf(str,"%s",argv[1]);
strcat(filename,str);
strcat(filename,"file");
fp=fopen(filename,"r");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `snprintf` to convert an integer into a string suitable for use in a file pathname.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int argument = atoi(argv[1]);
  char pathname[PATH_MAX];
  FILE *fp;

  snprintf(pathname, PATH_MAX, "/folder/item%dfile", argument);
  fp = fopen(pathname, "r");
  if (fp != NULL) {
    //do stuff to the file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/. It allows you to print to string buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
char filename[30];
sprintf(filename, "/folder/item%dfile", argv[1]);
```